# SQL Server : pattern matching

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching, sql-like

I'm trying to show string which has only complete word `chain` in it. Also wanted to know if there is something as `REGEX` similar to MySQL in SQL Server.

```
Select * 
From table
Where Name Like 'chain%'
```

Output:

```
Chain
Chain Stays 
Chainring   
Chainring Bolts 
Chainring Nut
```

Expected output:

```
Chain
Chain Stays
```

Since its an online question resources can be found here.

https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/adventureworks/sql-adventureworks-exercise-56.php

Comment: No regex in sql server as a quick google would show. Have you tried `'chain %'`

Comment: @dale-k NO `'chain %'` is not helpful. Also seen several websites but none was able to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure your search term and argument are properly delimited:

```
select * 
from table
where Concat(' ', Name, ' ') like '% chain %';
```